# Postmaster: Can we send HTML & Text in one email using multi-part MIME? If not, how do we line break in plain text?

Tags: postmaster, html-email

I have looked at the Postmaster docs, other questions on ee.stackexchange, and the Postmaster support forums at devot:ee, but have not seen an answer for these two.

1. Can Postmaster send a multi-part MIME message with HTML and plaintext via the expressionengine mail service?  If so, how?
2. If it can not send both HTML and plaintext in a single email, when sending in plaintext do I need to specify \r\n in the parcel code for linebreaks?  Is the preview pane supposed to show plaintext linebreaks, or does it only parse html?

My preference settings for sending text email in the parcel editor look like this:

- **Mail Type:** Text
- **Protocol:** Mail
- **Character Set:** UTF-8
- **CRLF:** \r\n
- **Newline:** \r\n

If have tried the following variations in the parcel editor:

```
Dear {screen_name},
blahblahblah

Dear {screen_name},\r\n
blahblahblah

Dear {screen_name},"\r\n"
blahblahblah
```

None of the above combinations show a linebreak in the preview window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default support for both HTML and plain text emails is a little limiting right now. In Postmaster v2, I am going to redo the UI and make it possible to have two different templates for HTML and plain text. There is no ETA on this, but this by far the most requested and desired feature. The underlying API is already setup (for the most part) to handle this, but the way it currently works is like this:

If you create a new parcel with an HTML template, it will strip the tags and attempt to format the email as best as it can for the plain text version. If plain text is used by default, then no html version will be sent. The preview pane however is always setup display HTML formatted emails. This is an oversight and an inherent flaw in Postmaster v1.x. In version 2, I will like be removing the preview pane all together in favor of saving templates as files and previewing them like a regular template.

The email should send properly with the line breaks though. It's the preview pain that won't respect them.

Comment: Justin, thanks very much for your detailed answer!  I will probably go with HTML since it does do some basic tag stripping.  I just want to confirm though if I do end up using plain text, do I need to use the \r\n notation for the linebreaks, or will the linebreaks be added automatically?